# Why does my code not return when I write in lower case?

Tags: python, lowercase

So I have this code:

```
welcome = input()
if (welcome.lower() == "Hello") or (welcome.lower() == "Hey") or (welcome.lower() == "Hej"):
    input("Hello,\n" + "my name is Misty.")
else:
    print ("That way of saying hello is new to me, should i save it in my memory?")
```

Why does this code not write hello back to me when I write lowercased Hello, Hey and Hej?

Comment: Why do you think `welcome.lower()` would ever equal `"Hello"` which has an uppercase character? Or the other ones?

Answer (score 4):

`lower` will convert *all* of the letters in a string to lower-case. Therefore, they will *never* compare equally to `"Hello"`, `"Hey"`, or `"Hej"` as each of those strings start with *1 uppercase letter*.

Instead try

```
if welcome.lower() in ('hello', 'hey', 'hej'):
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `welcome.lower()` can't be `"Hello"` really.

The purpose of lower() is to make the string all lowercase.

So, change like that:

```
if (welcome.lower() == "hello") or (welcome.lower() == "hey") or (welcome.lower() == "hej"):
```

Comment: thanks all of you, but what if i want to have it say the same to hello and Hello and so on? so that even if you write it uppercase or lover case it will stil say the same back?

Comment: cast every input to either `uppercase` or `lowercase` and then compare with `hello` and `HELLO` respectively. Both ways will work.